# After Switch statement code stops working and I am not able to type, I need to modify details in Files

Tags: c

The Code doesn't work as expected, The main focus is to modify through files, It stops during while loop and takes no input, Can Someone Please tell me what error is? also is the concept of modifying correct?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


void modify(){
    struct cust
{
    char ID[10];
    char name[25];
    char pnum[15];
    char bill[5];
    char IDn[10];
    char namen[25];
    char pnumn[15];
    char billn[5];
};
struct cust d1;
        struct cust d1;

        struct custnew
        {
            char IDn[10];
            char namen[25];
            char pnumn[15];
            char billn[5];
        };

        int a;
        a = 1;
        while (a == 1) {
            viewmod();
            char id[10];

            FILE *f, *fn;
            f = fopen("customer.txt", "r");
            fn = fopen("customertemp", "w");

            printf("Enter ID to be edited:");
            scanf("%s", &id);



            printf("Select option to be modified 1.ID  2.Name  3.P/No.  4.Bill  5.RETURN\n");

        int opt;
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        switch (opt)

        {
        case 1:
            while (!feof(f))
            {
                fscanf(f, "\nID : %s\tName : %s\tP/No. %s\tBill : %s \n ", &d1.ID, &d1.name, &d1.pnum, &d1.bill);
                if (strcmp(id, d1.ID)==0)
                {
                    printf("Enter New ID : ");//Repeats after entering
                    scanf("%s", &d1.IDn);
                    fprintf(fn, "\nID : %s\tName : %s\tP/No. %s\tBill : %s \n ", &d1.IDn, &d1.name, &d1.pnum, &d1.bill);

                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(fn, "\nID : %s\tName : %s\tP/No. %s\tBill : %s \n ", &d1.ID, &d1.name, &d1.pnum, &d1.bill);
                }

            }
                fclose(f);
                fclose(fn);
                remove("customer.txt");
                rename("customertemp.txt", "customer.txt");

                break;//More switch statements didn't provide due to repetitiveness 
                Default : printf("");

                return;
}
```

I am Using structs. The above code is for Modifying files, it takes a array from from struct and changes it
Edit : Now it runs until new ID and then gets me repeated time "Enter new id"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: edit : id is already initialized, id compares d1.ID and select line to be edited.

Comment: Please include the struct for `d2`

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, always post a [mcve]  otherwise the question will soon be closed as 'off topic'

Comment: there is no function defined in the posted code, the `#include` statement are missing,  The posted code does not compile.  please correct these problems